How to conditionally navigate to a Page based on if UserIsAvailable (obtained from Room database)
When the user starts the app, the app checks if there is a user (from room data base).
if userAvailable:
  show ProfilePage
else:
  show CreateUserPage.

My app -
@Composable
fun MyApp(){
  val navController = rememberNavController()
  val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()

  // UserDao.getUser returns Flow<User>
  val user = viewModel.user.collectAsState(initial = null)

  NavHost(navController, startDestination = UserCreateScreen){
         composable<ProfileScreen>{
               ProfilePage(user = user)
             }
         composable<UserCreateScreen>{
               if(user == null) CreateUserPage(onCreate = viewModel.createUser)
               else ProfilePage(user = user)
             }

     }
}

The problem is that since  viewModel.user.collectAsState is asynchronus, during startup user is always null and the app always shows CreateUserPage regardless whether user is available.
Is there a way to wait(in the meantime show loading screen) until the user is fethched then check the following -
if(user == null) CreateUserPage(onCreate = viewModel.createUser)
else ProfilePage(user = user)

